In SSIS, how to reference tables/data created/inserted earlier in the process?
I am in the process of teaching myself SSIS, and I've run into something I'm having trouble figuring out. I'm going to simplify the issue a bit, for ease of discussion. I am developing using VS 2022 against a Sql Server 2022 database.
Basically, I have a package that sets up a database, i.e. creates tables, then adds indices, foreign keys, and so on. The step after all that is to create views based upon the newly created tables, and it is there that the problem arises. The step to create views fails at run time, because the underlying table isn't recognized. The precise error message is:

Error: 0xC002F210 at Create View vw_ViewName, Execute SQL Task:
Executing the query "CREATE VIEW [dbo].[vw_ViewName] AS SEL..." failed
with the following error: "Invalid object name 'dbo.TableName'.".

The following image shows how I've set things up... the screenshot was taken showing the results of the run.

I figured that the table creations hadn't been committed yet, and that's why the Create Views Package cannot see the tables. So, I decided to try transactions to see if that would work. My next attempt looked like this:

I have tried various settings for the TraansactionOption and IsolationLevel settings, but nothing I've tried yet works.
Now, as I said at the beginning, this is a simplified example. In the real project, not only do I have to create the views, but I also have to import data into those tables... something impossible until I can commit the table creations. Some of the tables have to be used as lookups later in the process, as well.
So, any suggestions as to what I am doing wrong and how I can accomplish what I need to do? Right now I have multiple solutions that have to be run in sequence, all because of this little issue, and this is completely unacceptable. There has to be a way, and I'm hoping someone can help me out here.

Embed your CREATE VIEW into a SQL EXECUTE statement.  This will work at runtime without falling apart

Strange, but after you run it once, does it work creating views? It's kinda weird to create tables and views, etc in SSIS i gotta say, usually it's done ahead of time

SSIS tries to validate before it runs.  If you right click on the step giving you issues and go to properties there is a setting for Delay Validation  you can set that to True.  I believe this is the setting you have to change to make it run.  You will have to set this on each task that is giving you the issues.

It is, eventually. The control flow for the CreateViews package is composed of three "Execute T-SQL Statement Tasks," one for each view I need to create. The package fails with the error given above on the first of the T-SQL tasks.

Brad, I just tried setting the delay validation to true on both the package and each T-SQL task inside that package. Same error.

Sigge, I cannot get it to work if the CreateViews is in the same solution as the table creation stuff. If I put the CreateViews package in a SEPARATE solution that runs after the  first one completes, it works fine.

Strange, cause i guess foreign keys against the tables work? Perhaps your VIEW package is ran in wrong db or something silly like that?
